# Fonticon color not changing on Hover

Tags: css, font-awesome

HTML:

```
<div class="postleftmen">
        <header class="clearfix">
            <span>Post Ad</span>
            <h1>Select categlory</h1>
        </header>
        <ul class="cbp-vimenu">
            <li><a href="#" class="">Logo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="flaticon-smart"></i>Archive</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="flaticon-smart">Search</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="flaticon-baby110">Pencil</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="icon-location">Location</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="icon-images">Images</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="download">Download</a></li>
        </ul>
```

am trying to change the font icon color on hover

```
class="flaticon-smart"
```

code used to ling font icon

visited this link [CSS, changing hover effect of icon font in a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354157/css-changing-hover-effect-of-icon-font-in-a-link) and changed in my code but its not work

CSS

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Flaticon";
src: url("flaticon.eot");
src: url("flaticon.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
url("flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
url("flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
url("flaticon.svg") format("svg");
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
[class^="flaticon-"]:before, [class*=" flaticon-"]:before,
[class^="flaticon-"]:after, [class*=" flaticon-"]:after {   
font-family: Flaticon;
font-size: 10px;
font-style: normal;
margin-left: 10px;
}
.flaticon-smart:before {
content: "\e038";
    color: #9999ff;
}
```

Comment: Where's you CSS to change the font color?

Comment: Can you upload your code to a public accessible site - with Flaticon installed?

Comment: u want to check code or website run method

Comment: I cannot experiment with FontIcon at the moment, so I'd like to see some live code to experiment with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want  to use JQuery, you can use the [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function

First include JQuery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

and then

```
$(document).ready(function()    {
    $('.flaticon-smart').hover(function(){
        $(this).css('color', '#f00');
    });
});
```

**Edit**

If you want to do it with CSS put this in the `<head> </head>` section

```
<style>
    .flaticon-smart:hover{
        color: #f00;
    }
</style>
```

The color changes back to the original when you stop hovering the link. 
If you want it changed permanently use the JQuery solution

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using jQuery at all. Instead, do this.

REGULAR OR NORMAL MODE

```
[class^="flaticon-"]:before, [class*=" flaticon-"]:before, [class^="flaticon-"]:after, [class*=" flaticon-"]:after {color: $smoke;}
```

HOVER OR MOUSEOVER MODE

```
[class^="flaticon-"]:hover:before, [class*=" flaticon-"]:hover:before, 
[class^="flaticon-"]:hover:after, [class*=" flaticon-"]:hover:after  {color: $red;}
```

RECAP:

REGULAR OR NORMAL MODE: element:after, element::after or element:before, element::before (no change)

HOVER OR MOUSEOVER MODE: element:hover::after or element:hover::before (change)

I hope that made sense and good luck to you.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after