# Hover effect affecting both SVG icon and text content in a HTML link element

Tags: html, css, svg, effects, user-experience

Let's say I have the following HTML:

```
<a href="#">
 <svg class="icon">
 <!-- SVG content -->
 </svg>
 Link text
</a>
```

And the following CSS:

```
a:hover {
  color: #0074D9;
}

icon:hover {
  fill: #0074D9;
}
```

Now I want a hover effect (let's say a color change) that acts on the whole `a` group. That is, the user should see *both* the icon and the text changing color when hovering over the `a` element.

Something like this (from the Instapaper website):

[image: instapaper]

Right now, using the markup and the style rules above, i'm only able to get this on Chrome:

[image: myapp]

Hovering over the text doesn't affect the icon. Hovering over the icon works:

[image: myapp2]

Seems like a trivial task but after some failed attempts I realized that I'm probably missing something.

Comment: Um, how about `a:hover > .icon{fill:#0074D9}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354157/css-changing-hover-effect-of-icon-font-in-a-link) right after I posted my question...

Basically I need to "set the color of the icon class that is inside a hovered a element".

So this works for me:

```
a:hover .icon {
  fill: $0074D9;  
}
```